# Is it possible to redirect a non-existent page?

Tags: javascript, redirect

Current path: user clicks link -> link directs user to a non-existent page -> non-existent page directs user to the homepage -> homepage redirects user to a newer version of the homepage.

All these links have the same root, lets say; www.website.com. Is it possible to redirect users regardless of the website's path, as long as it contains the same root? ie. if www.website.com/cat/dog/sheep/hello/ doesn't exist, can I redirect it to a existing webpage with Javascript?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
window.location.replace("www.website.com/existing/");
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: No. That page has to exist, in other words: the server has to send a valid response. So what you describe is possible using some serverside scripting.

Comment: What are you using for the web server? This is not possible when serving a static site from plain files in a folder, but nearly every server setup has ways to return some "not found" page when the path doesn't match an existing page.